# git reset --hard results in some missing files

Tags: xcode, git

I got to go back to a previous commit, I used the git reset --hard command:

```
git reset --hard ff680b51a3f3d7d695bbef0367cfe7b75d9be60e
```

However, I noticed that my project is now compiling with error like:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SetupDishViewController", referenced from:
```

The file called `SetupDishViewController` is obviously missing, I am sure it was there when I commit the `ff680b51a3f3d7d695bbef0367cfe7b75d9be60e`, I double check that on the remote branch to make sure and it's there.

How to restore it? Is there any way to pull that commit back from remote branch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, find the hash of the commit and do:

```
$ git cherry-pick <hash-of-commit>
```

Comment: Hi,the hash of the commit is `ff680b51a3f3d7d695bbef0367cfe7b75d9be60e`, I ran a cherry pick but the same file is still missing and the same error I got.

Comment: Probably this was not the proper commit. You can run `$ git log -p SetupDishViewController` and see in which commit it was deleted. Then you can either revert that commit with `$ git revert <sha1-of-commit>` or do an interactive rebase (`$ git rebase -i <sha1-of-commit>`) and edit it to keep only the changes it should do and not the bad ones (ie. deleting the file).

Comment: I revert to that commit, git say: `You are currently reverting commit ff680b5.` I got few obvious conflicts which I fixed and commit again, however the file in question is not listed in the project, I am quite sure it's on that commit because I double check the remote repo :)

Comment: Have you found the commit that deleted the file?

Comment: Actually I didn't deleted it in any commit, I worked on that file along all commits and it will remain on the project for later commits too

Comment: Are you sure that it was tracked by git then in the first place? If you do `$ git log SetupDishViewController` what result do you get?

Comment: `git log -- SetupDishViewController` doesn't print any log history for that file, just a blank terminal with the `(END)`

Comment: Ok, the revert operation seems to be working, but after `git revert --continue`, I got the following popup message: `The document “COMMIT_EDITMSG” could not be opened. The file doesn’t exist.`, any idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of `git` you can try to get back a recent version of that file with:

```
git reset @{2.days.ago}  SetupDishViewController
```

Using the `@{date}` notation you can specify a time interval like `yesterday` or `"1 month ago"`.